# WPF Replacing AND extending styles

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

How do I change what WPF's idea of the *default* style for a control is?  And why is this happening in the first place?   In the below XAML, I declare a Style for Button, and then further declare a new Style that overrides one of the setters called "HugeBut".  I would expect that HugeBut is implicitly BasedOn my new un-named style, but apparently it is not;

```
<Window.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
          <Border Background="Red">
            <ContentPresenter/>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>

  <!-- badness -->
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="HugeBut">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
  </Style>

  <!-- works, but I do not want to explicitly set the based-on. -->
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="HugeBut" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
  </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Button Content="Regular" />
<Button Content="huge!" Style="{StaticResource HugeBut}"/>
```

You would expect two red buttons, one with black text and one with yellow, but Style HugeBut inherits all of the values that I did not specify in my unnamed style from the system default theme for Button (Aero in my case).

What can I do to change this behavior?

Comment: HugeBut(t)?!! I think you have to specify BasedOn. If you don't how will it know to base that style on some other?

Comment: I certainly *don't* need to specify BasedOn when I am extending the Default Style of a control.  I would like to get into a situation where the values everything else falls back to are completely of my choosing, and NEVER sourced automatically out of the Default style, unless I desire that.

Comment: It is actually the other way around. It is ALWAYS sourced out out the Default style, unless you specify some other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the answer is here:

http://wpfthemereplacer.codeplex.com/

From the site description:

> This library allows users to provide their own resource dictionaries
>   to replace the default theme dictionaries loaded by WPF. This makes it
>   so you don't have to decorate custom styles with
>   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ...}}" when your own custom theme is
>   being used in your application. It also makes it so if you have custom
>   controls that just provide enhanced capability and don't need to
>   replace the the style, you don't need to define a new style or
>   override the DefaultStyleKey when you create the custom control.

This is exactly what I'm looking for.  This will allow me to use Styles as they are meant to be used across an app that has been extensively "re-themed", rather than theme-ing by setting global styles (and then deal with tracking down bits of code that are missing BasedOn, or cannot deal with it at all due to WPF bugs and other constraints)

Answer (score 0):

> works, but I do not want to explicitly set the based-on.

Well, the framework does not really care if you don't want to, for all i know, you *have to*.

Comment: The design of the style system is that "in absence of a basedOn style, go to the default".  I want to change what it ends up selecting as the default, not the behavior of the basedOn tag.